# Select all & Unselect all not working in the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want select & unselect all using button.

The first time I select and unselect the code below works, but the second time, my button is not working.

**HTML :**

```
<button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main"> Select </button>
<button type="button" id="unselectAll" class="main"> UnSelect </button>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#selectAll").on("click", function() {

  $("#example tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input").attr('checked', true);
  });
});

$("#unselectAll").on("click", function() {

  $("#example tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input").removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wwzaw89/4/)

How can I solve this?

Comment: by the way `$("#example tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input")` ... why not `$("#example tr input").each(function() {` and skip the find :p

Comment: @JaromandaX even the `each` is redundant

Comment: indeed you are correct

Comment: Sorry guys, i got another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522658/select-checkbox-select-row-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use prop() instead of attr() and you can combine them together something like:

```js
$("#selectAll, #unselectAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectAll = this.id === 'selectAll';
  // no need for `each` ... jQuery will do that internally already
  $("#example tbody :checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main"> Select </button>
<button type="button" id="unselectAll" class="main"> UnSelect </button>

<table id="example" class="myclass" />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Employee Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>varun</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Rahuk</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>johm Doe</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Lara</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Jay</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Franciso</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop` instead of `attr` and `removeAttr` per this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/)

Sample:

```js
$("#selectAll").on("click", function() {

  $("#example tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input").prop("checked", true);
  });
});

$("#unselectAll").on("click", function() {

  $("#example tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main"> Select </button>
<button type="button" id="unselectAll" class="main"> UnSelect </button>

<table id="example" class="myclass" />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Employee Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>varun</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Rahuk</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>johm Doe</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Lara</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Jay</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Franciso</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

hope u will like it

```js
$("document").ready(function()
{ 
 $("#mcb").change(function() 
 {
  $("#example tbody :checkbox").prop("checked", $("#mcb").prop("checked"));
  // choose by element or id 
  $("#example tbody #scb").prop("checked", $("#mcb").prop("checked"));
 });
 
 $("[id='scb']").change(function() 
 {
  if($(this).prop("checked")==false)
  {
   $("#mcb").prop("checked",false);
  }

  var tf=true;
  $("#example tbody #scb").each(function() 
  {
      if($(this).prop("checked")==false)
   {tf=false;}
    });
  $("#mcb").prop("checked",tf);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example"/>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><input id="mcb" type="checkbox" /></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Employee Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>varun</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Rahuk</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>johm Doe</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Lara</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Jay</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="scb"  type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Franciso</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, but i got another problem. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522658/select-checkbox-select-row-table)