# Select Checkbox !== Select Row Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

The `select/unselect` button **works on the checkbox.**

But it **does not work for the row table.**

```
//Select row table
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $row = $(this),
    isSelected = $row.hasClass('selected')
  $row.toggleClass('selected')
    .find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isSelected);
});

// Problem : Checkbox !== select row
$("#selectAll, #unselectAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectAll = this.id === 'selectAll';
  $("#example tr :checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);
});
```

I think the checklist is just for display, for row selected and to mark it.

> How  when the select / unselect button is clicked,
>
> it select on row
>   table too, Not just on the checkbox?

You can see if you click the row table.

**Code Snippet Demonstration :**

```js
$('#example').dataTable();

//Select row table
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $row = $(this),
    isSelected = $row.hasClass('selected')
  $row.toggleClass('selected')
    .find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isSelected);
});

// Problem : Checkbox !== select row
$("#selectAll, #unselectAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectAll = this.id === 'selectAll';
  $("#example tr :checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" id="selectAll"> Select </button>
<button type="button" id="unselectAll"> UnSelect </button>

<table id="example" class="myclass" />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Employee Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Calvin</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Ananda</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>US</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/3k4mjL0n/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to call `.toggleClass()` on the rows providing the [second argument](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) that says whether to add or remove the class:

```
  $("#example tr").toggleClass("selected", selectAll)
    .find(":checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);
```

Added to your demo:

```js
$('#example').dataTable();

//Select row table
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $row = $(this),
    isSelected = $row.hasClass('selected')
  $row.toggleClass('selected')
    .find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isSelected);
});

// Problem : Checkbox !== select row
$("#selectAll, #unselectAll").on("click", function() {
  var selectAll = this.id === 'selectAll';
  $("#example tr").toggleClass("selected", selectAll)
    .find(":checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" id="selectAll"> Select </button>
<button type="button" id="unselectAll"> UnSelect </button>
<table id="example" class="myclass" />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Employee Type</th><th>Address</th><th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Calvin</td><td>TCS</td><td>IT</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>US</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Ananda</td><td>TCS</td><td>IT</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>US</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>John</td><td>TCS</td><td>IT</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>US</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Doe</td><td>TCS</td><td>IT</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>US</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Not work when i want execute that selected. I need to choose one row so this will works.. [The Problem](https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-94c11ca055.gif)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I really like your work.
but you can see, after I click 'select all' and will copy it, it does not work. in the picture, I need to select 1 row first after click 'select all' so the copy process will running well.

Comment: What copy process? You seem to be asking about functionality not shown in the question. Also, I don't know what you mean by selecting one row first after clicking Select All.

Comment: Not like that I mean, it's like 'select all' has not chosen row perfectly.

Comment: Solved, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#example').dataTable();
   //Select row table
 $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
   var $row = $(this);
   isSelected = $row.hasClass('selected')
   $row.toggleClass('selected').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',!isSelected);
 });

 //Checkbox !== select row
 var isSelectAll = false;
 var isUnselectAll = false;
 $("#selectAll, #unselectAll").on("click", function() {

   var selectAll = this.id === 'selectAll';
   if(selectAll){
     if(!isSelectAll){
     $('#example tr').click();
   }
     isSelectAll = true;
     isUnselectAll = false;
   }else{
     if(!isUnselectAll){
        $('#example tr').click();
    }
    isSelectAll = false;
    isUnselectAll = true;
  }


$("#example tr :checkbox").prop('checked', selectAll);

});
```

Comment: Cool... Thank you for your work.
that's very helpful.